# Pipeline hangs after starting Azurite

Tags: azure-pipelines, integration-testing, azurite

[image: Hanging pipeline]

I used the following yml content. Used Azurite 3.15 and 3.9. But no luck. Then I tried as separate jobs. Still unable to pass the integration test.

```
 stages:
    - stage: Publish
      displayName: 'Build and Publish Artifacts'
      jobs:
      - job: 'NGKMediaManagementAPI'
        steps:
        - task: NodeTool@0 
          inputs:
             versionSpec: 13.x
        - script : npm install -g azurite@3.9.0
        - script : mkdir azurite
        - script : azurite
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the hanging issue and Passed the Init tests(based on Azurite) in pipeline.
use the following command in your yml file.
Most importantly **start /B azurite** will remove the hanging issue !!!

```
 - task: NodeTool@0 
      inputs:
         versionSpec: 13.x
    - script : npm install -g azurite
      displayName: Install Azurite
    - script : start /B azurite
      displayName: Start azurite
```

below is success the pipeline [image]

Answer (score 0):

When starting Azurite, the default is for it to block the command prompt you're running it on which makes the pipeline appear to hang.

Run the command from PowerShell and [Use the background operator to start a background job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.2#example-2--use-the-background-operator-to-start-a-background-job).

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      npm install -g azurite
      azurite &
```

More information: [Run automated tests by using Azurite - Run tests on Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/use-azurite-to-run-automated-tests#run-tests-on-azure-pipelines). In this example they use the `& operator` in Bash which also directs the shell to run the command in the background.

Other interesting commands around this are [Get-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-job?view=powershell-7.2), [Stop-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/stop-job?view=powershell-7.2) and [Remove-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-job?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :) But when using azurite & I got issue as The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string. Then I used as azurite "&" . This resolve issue but still azurite up and hangs my pipeline. I am using Windows 2022